# How to disable "Your page has X new views"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-notifications

I keep receiving annoying and useless notifications for my Facebook pages:

[image: Facebook page has new views]

**QUESTION: How to disable these notifications?**
I don't want to be notified about new views nor new likes and post likes.

---

I clicked both of these buttons, for each page, many times, with zero improvement:

[image: Get fewer notifications like this]

In each page's notification settings, I have "New Likes" turned off, and I can't find any setting about views:

[image: Facebook page notifications settings]

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to turn off page view notifications specifically.

To reduce the notifications you can change the notification settings **On Facebook** option.

Currently you have chosen the first option (look at last screenshot of your question *On Facebook*).
Change that to the second option to reduce the number of notifications or third option for no notifications. These options will affect all the notification.